# How to join columns in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have opened a dataframe in julia where i have 3 columns like this:

```
day   month    year
1       1      2011
2       4      2015
3       12     2018
```

how can I make a new column called date that goes:

```
day   month    year    date
1       1      2011    1/1/2011
2       4      2015    2/4/2015
3       12     2018    3/12/2018
```

I was trying with this:

```
df[!,:date]= df.day.*"/".*df.month.*"/".*df.year
```

but it didn't work.

in R i would do:

```
df$date=paste(df$day, df$month, df$year, sep="/")
```

is there anything similar?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julia has an inbuilt `Date` type in its standard library:

```
julia> using Dates

julia> df[!, :date] = Date.(df.year, df.month, df.day)
3-element Vector{Date}:
 2011-01-01
 2015-04-02
 2018-12-03
```

Comment: Thanks!! This was exactly what I wanted! Is there any documentation on the Date library?

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/

Comment: Typing `?Dates` also gives a short summary and some examples, which might be a better starting point - the manual can be... rather comprehensive when you're looking for basic usage.